# using a variable value on css modules class name

Tags: css, reactjs, next.js, css-modules, react-css-modules

I'm trying use use a variable  in a class name with css modules in nextjs, but I'm having a bad time figuring out the right syntax.

my variable comes from the api:

`const type = red`

how i'm trying to do it:

`` <div className={` ${styles.background} ${styles.--type}`}></div> ``

The result that I expect:

`` <div className={` ${styles.background} ${styles.--red}`></div> ``

is there a way to do it?

Comment: You mean `styles[type]`? You seem to be mixing up CSS variables with regular JavaScript variables.

Comment: i'm not using any css variables actually, I just want to use a variable value as a class name with css modules

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not sure what you are trying to achieve.

One solution could be to do :

```
const type = 'red';

<div className={`${styles.background} ${styles.type}`}></div>
```

However if you want to use BEM and the `--` notation. You' might have to switch to brackets notation.

```
const type = '--red';

<div className={`${styles.background} ${styles[type]}`}></div>
```

Comment: I believe the first solution still needs bracket notation around `type`